# CSS Block that goes to the end of the page but doesn't activate scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Look at the picture below, the purple square that I have created needs to go to the end of the page always and it cannot activate horizontal scroll or push the screen. The version I have is with a fixed width, but that doesn't work response wise, example: the laptop resolution pushes the content to the right because of it (look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u67M3.png ). For mobile xs version I have hidden it, so it's just for screens md, lg and xl.

[image]

I used Bootstrap for the grid creation. Here is the code for the right section (where the purple is):

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-sm-12 job-details">
                <div class="job-title"> Some title <div class="bgendsqaure"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="inner-job">
                    <div class="job-timelocation"> Subtitle </div>
                    <div class="job-info">
                        - Designing web applications & mobile apps <br>
                        - Developing responsive websites using HTML, CSS, JavaScript <br>
                        - Execution of sql queries in microsoft sql server <br>
                        - Development of apps using git <br>
                        - Project management using jira with everyday team meetings <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

SCSS:

```
    .job-details {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.job-title {
    padding: 20px;
    background: $maincolor;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.bgendsqaure {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;

    width: 394px;
    height: 71px;
    background: #cf9bff;
    position: absolute;
    right: -378px;
    top: 0;
    display:none; /* hide */

}

.job-timelocation {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #4454cf14;
    text-align: center;
}

.job-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

@include xl {
    .job-timelocation {
        margin-left: 33px;
        margin-right: 33px;
    }

    .bgendsqaure {
        display: inline;
    }

    .job-hide {
        display: none;
    }
}

@include xs {
    .explist {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .stitle {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

---

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4qeodk1/

Comment: please correct me if I misunderstood. Do you want the blue line to stay fixed on the top right and move along with the scroll ? And why did you make it so large ?

Comment: is it possible to show exactly what you want to look like

Comment: @CanUver I want to to look exactly like it is right now in the picture, but I don't want the screen to be pushed out because it's fixed width. I want it to go you.